# Does OpenGL ES need to be "shutdown"?

Tags: iphone, ios4, opengl-es, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller with a view that uses OpenGL ES.  When that view controller is deallocated, is there any other work that needs to be done to "shut down" OpenGL?  Or once the view controller doesn't exist, will the phone switch out of 'OpenGL mode'--if such a thing exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real "OpenGL mode".  On iOS, you create a context to do your rendering within via the EAGLContext class:

```
context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
```

Within this context, you'll need to set up at least one framebuffer object (FBO) and attach it to the CAEAGLLayer in which you do your actual drawing:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &viewFramebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);

[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
```

You specify the current context before doing any OpenGL ES drawing:

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]
```

and then that drawing is rendered into your FBO attached to the CAEAGLLayer, which causes it to be displayed onscreen.  This content is composited with the rest of your interface, so there's no real change of mode to do OpenGL drawing, it's just another view in your interface.

When you're done with the view that is hosting your OpenGL content, you don't need to turn anything off, but it would be a good idea to clean up any resources you've used.  Use `glDeleteFramebuffers()` and `glDeleteRenderbuffers()` to clean up your FBOs, `glDeleteTextures()` for any textures you've used, `glDeleteBuffers()` for any VBOs, etc.

Comment: Thanks Brad!  That's what I was thinking, but I wanted to hear it from a pro.